# Is there a way to stop iOS 8.1 Safari hiding fixed elements on checkbox and radio input focus?

Tags: mobile-safari, ios8.1

Mobile Safari 'unfixes' fixed elements on input focus where a keyboard or a list select appears on the screen. This makes sense as screen space is limited.

On iOS 6 and 7, Safari would do nothing on checkboxes and radio buttons, which made sense because no extra elements are shown on screen. It's just a tap to interact.

But iOS 8 hides the fixed elements even on checkbox and radio inputs and their respective labels. **This makes no sense**.

Is there a way to fix it **without** resorting using fake elements and implementing input change with javascript?